# cts:value-match is not returning the actual result in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to get the count of files based on the cts:element-value-match range defined inside cts:value-match function.

Below is my xquery which I am trying. It returns me the result after considering both the argument of the cts:element-value-match but not as a conditional check.
The requirement is to check multiple element range indexes as the search condition and use that as conditional check .
Is that possible??

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
cts:count(
((cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("SubmissionUser"),"System"),
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("Partner"),"Ellerma")
),("unordered")),100)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the criteria are that you are attempting to test and search for? Also, are you attempting to count the values that match your criteria, or count how many documents have elements with certain values? It isn't clear from your description and your current code. It seems that you may have some parens in the wrong spot AND may need to adjust the way that you are querying, but not quite sure what you are searching for and attempting to count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to count the documents where SubmissionUser=System AND Partner=Ellerma.

A few notes:

- the value-matches are returning matched values.  That is, 'System' and 'Ellerma', not documents.
- therefore, you can use an element-range-query in search to find the documents that match both constraints.
- the range indexes will be exact, so you can use estimate rather than count

So maybe

```
xdmp:estimate(
    cts:search (/, 
        cts:and-query ((
           cts:element-range-query (xs:QName("SubmissionUser"), "=", "System"),
           cts:element-range-query (xs:QName("Partner"), "=", "Ellerma")
        ))
    )
)
```